# Как получить id пользователя, который зашел на сервер дивкорд?

Tags: python, бот, discord.py

Как автоматически получать id пользователя, при входе на сервер в дискорд?
Вот наброски

```
@client.event
async def on_ready(ctx):
    memberid = ctx.get_user(id)
    print(str(memberid))
```

Answer (score 1):

[`on_member_join(member)`](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.on_member_join)

```py
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    print(member.id)
```